# Fabric and virtualenv working on Ubuntu but not on Solaris

Tags: django, ubuntu, solaris, fabric, virtualenvwrapper

I have a project that runs on Ubuntu and Solaris. Fabric works fine with Ubuntu but does not on Solaris. If I try something inside a virtualenv it fails with `workon: command not found`.

This is how my fabfile.py looks like:

```
with prefix('workon %s' % env.virtualenv):
    sudo('manage.py collectstatic --noinput')
```

I put those lines in .profile on both platforms:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source /path/to/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

That's all I've done. Why does Ubuntu work but Solaris doesn't? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's Virtualenvwrapper that's failing, not Fabric or Virtualenv. Try using Virtualenv directly with:

```
with prefix('source path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate'):
    sudo('manage.py collectstatic --noinput')
```

EDIT:

to try to fix virtualenvwrapper, try wrapping your code in the following, and see if it solves the original error.

```
with prefix('source path/to/virtualenvwrapper.sh'):
```

Comment: But why is it failing? I would rather fix it as to work around the issue. And I prefer simpler solutions like `workon foobar` where I don't have to type the whole path for my virtualenv.
But I like your pragmatic approach as it solves my problem. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why it's failing, You haven't provided enough information to debug that. See my edit for possible mitigation. Also, If I solved your problem, can you mark my answer as accepted please?

Answer (score 0):

Consider where you have put the following?

```
export WORKON_HOME=/opt/virtual_envs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

According to man bash, the -l flag, that fabric issues, will cause the the following to happen

[bash] looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.

I had this bootstrap code in .bashrc, which wasn't being sourced by bash -l.  I moved those two lines to .profile, and can now do the fabric lines below.  (I don't have .bash_profile or .bash_login)

```
with cd('/www/code'):
    with prefix('workon code'):
        run('./manage.py validate')
```